# Teradata FOR CURSOR to SQL Server object

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, cursor, teradata

I am fairly new to Teradata and I am trying to migrate a big stored procedure to SQL Server (T-SQL). I have a cursor statement (below) which I am trying to make sense. Its a cursor for sure, but the FOR in front is confusing me.

```
     FOR clmn_cursor2 AS clmn_cursor2 CURSOR FOR
             SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(cmd.src_attr_txt)) src_attrib,
                                               case 
                                               when (CHARINDEX(' as ' ,cmd.src_attr_txt)> 0) 
                                               then SUBSTRING(cmd.src_attr_txt,CHARINDEX(' as ',LTRIM(cmd.src_attr_txt))+4, LEN(cmd.src_attr_txt))
                                               else SUBSTRING(cmd.src_attr_txt,CHARINDEX('.' ,LTRIM(cmd.src_attr_txt))+1, LEN(cmd.src_attr_txt))
                                               end 'col_null_var'
                          FROM  t_srch_res_cfg cmd WHERE cmd.srch_catg_id= @search_cat_id
                          ORDER BY cmd.attr_disp_ord
      DO
             SET @v_select_stmt = @v_select_stmt + clmn_cursor2.src_attrib;
             SET @v_col_null_stmt = (v_col_null_stmt) + 'NULL as ' + (clmn_cursor2.col_null_var)
      END FOR;
```

What does the above code mean? I figured out the select part, but cant make sense of the FOR CURSOR thing. How best can I implement this on SQL Server 2012?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. Just putting this out so that someone could use it.
The above is a Cursor with a for loop. It will append each and every row from the select statement and create a single statement.